# WPF Editable XAMDataGrid combobox ElementName binding works in .net 4.0 but not in 3.5

Tags: wpf, binding, xamdatagrid

I have a user control that has a xamdatagrid added to a grid as:

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>

        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding ElementName=grid1, Path=DataContext.Test}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Key"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding}" Name="xamDataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout>
                <igDP:Field Name="Name" >
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}"/>
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I am setting the DataContext for grid1 in the code-behind in the constructor. This works with WPF 4.0 but not 3.5. With 3.5, I get the "Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=grid1'" error.For making the binding work with 3.5, I had to use ObjectDataProvider as:

```
<Grid Name="grid1">
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myData" ObjectType="{x:Type local:ViewModel}"></ObjectDataProvider>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}">
            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource myData}, Path=Test}"/>
            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="Key"/>
        </Style>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <igDP:XamDataGrid DataSource="{Binding}" Name="xamDataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
        <igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
            <igDP:FieldLayout>
                <igDP:Field Name="Name" >
                    <igDP:Field.Settings>
                        <igDP:FieldSettings EditorType="{x:Type igEditors:XamComboEditor}"/>
                    </igDP:Field.Settings>
                </igDP:Field>
            </igDP:FieldLayout>
        </igDP:XamDataGrid.FieldLayouts>
    </igDP:XamDataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Is there any known reason behind why the ElementName binding in the first code snippet does not work with WPF 3.5 or have I done something wrong there? Thanks in adv.